# How to use dataset.shard in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

Recently I am looking into the dataset API in Tensorflow, and there is a method `dataset.shard()` which is for distributed computations.

This is what's stated in Tensorflow's documentation:

```
Creates a Dataset that includes only 1/num_shards of this dataset.

d = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(FLAGS.input_file)
d = d.shard(FLAGS.num_workers, FLAGS.worker_index)
d = d.repeat(FLAGS.num_epochs)
d = d.shuffle(FLAGS.shuffle_buffer_size)
d = d.map(parser_fn, num_parallel_calls=FLAGS.num_map_threads)
```

This method is said to return a portion of the original dataset. If I have two workers, am I supposed to do:

```
d_0 = d.shard(FLAGS.num_workers, worker_0)
d_1 = d.shard(FLAGS.num_workers, worker_1)
......
iterator_0 = d_0.make_initializable_iterator()
iterator_1 = d_1.make_initializable_iterator()

for worker_id in workers:
    with tf.device(worker_id):
        if worker_id == 0:
            data = iterator_0.get_next()
        else:
            data = iterator_1.get_next()
        ......
```

Because the documentation did not specify how to make subsequent calls, I am a bit confused here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

You should take a look at the [tutorial on Distributed TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/deploy/distributed) first to better understand how it works.

You have multiple workers, that each run the same code but with a small difference: each worker will have a different `FLAGS.worker_index`.

When you use [`tf.data.Dataset.shard`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#shard), you will supply this worker index and the data will be split between workers equally.

Here is an example with 3 workers.

```py
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.range(6)
dataset = dataset.shard(FLAGS.num_workers, FLAGS.worker_index)


iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
res = iterator.get_next()

# Suppose you have 3 workers in total
with tf.Session() as sess:
    for i in range(2):
        print(sess.run(res))
```

We will have the output:

- `0, 3` on worker 0
- `1, 4` on worker 1
- `2, 5` on worker 2

Comment: Do I need to do this when I use Estimator's `train_and_evaluate()` with TF_CONFIG properly set for distributed training? or is sharding handled internally?

Comment: How is it different from not using shard calling iterator.get_next() in the loop?

Comment: The point of using `tf.data.Dataset.shard` is when you have multiple workers, and each worker should have its own subset of the dataset.

Comment: @OlivierMoindrot Please take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55998385/tensorflow-dataset-for-multiple-gpus

Comment: @OlivierMoindrot can you take a look at this question, https://stackoverflow.com/q/58926940/5904928 why there is huge difference between lstm final output vs state output.